# F# code quotations: can I define my own concrete and abstract syntax?

Tags: f#, quasiquotes

In Haskell I can use the quasiquoter to produce a custom AST using concrete syntax defined by custom parser, as described here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Quasiquotation

Is this possible in F#?

Comment: F# has [code quotations](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualfsharpdocs/blob/master/docs/conceptual/code-quotations-%5Bfsharp%5D.md) which give you the AST. But it doesn't generate types.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I can think of is F#'s TypeProviders.
It allows provider code to be part of the compiler pipeline, and constructs types to be injected.

For example, there's the XML type provider:

```
type Author = XmlProvider<"""<author name="Paul Feyerabend" born="1924" />""">
let sample = Author.Parse("""<author name="Karl Popper" born="1902" />""")

printfn "%s (%d)" sample.Name sample.Born
```

For more, see the [FSharp.Data project](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/).

Comment: Its important to note that type providers ironically cant actually create any F# specific types.

Comment: Absolutely. They create short-lived types which only "exist" for the compiler, and don't make it to the assembly.

Comment: Your thinking of erased type providers.  Generative type providers create real types that exist in your target assembly.

Comment: I thought we were talking about the same thing. What exactly did you mean by F# specific types?

Comment: Records, discriminated unions, function types.  You can only output nominal classes.